# Running Compiz on Ubuntu-studio

Tags: 13.04, compiz, ubuntu-studio, xfce4

I've installed Ubuntu Studio, and includes XFCE4. I've installed Compiz, but don't know how to use it.

Can I use Compiz?

Comment: You could try to replace xfwm4 (xfce windows manager) with compiz by open a terminal and type `compiz --replace`

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users/118004/ubuntu)'s comment, it is possible to use/run compiz by typing in terminal: `compiz --replace`

Comment: But how to make Ubuntu Studio use Compiz by default, rather than having to manually run `compiz --replace` in each session?